# Magento determine if report script is running

Tags: magento, controller, report

I have created a Magento module that will, based on some filters, create a CSV file with the order data. This report takes anytime from 15–40 min to run depending on the selected filters. Since there is a lot of data, I used straight queries to generate the report.

So what I am trying to do now, is to make sure that when this report is being generated, no one else can run it. So I need to be able to detect that the query is running. Any suggestions on the best approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

create a file called report.lock when you start the report. Check to see if this file exists when you start the report and return an error if it does, otherwise create the file. Delete it once it is complete.